# DataTable with contextMenu, multipleSelection, rowEdit

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

So I have a pretty complex dataTable. It should be able to edit a single row, to select multiple rows, and to display a contextmenu for each row. Single row editing works fine, multiple selection works aswell, the only problem that I have is that whenever I try to open a contextMenu on the right-clicked row, the value of the selected tableItem is null. It works only if I click explicit on the row(left click) and afterwards right click for the context menu to show up. This is very inconvenient, I want on rightClick the contextMenu to show up with the selected itemValue.

I know there have been some other posts regarding this issue, but there was no real solution or workaround, so I hope you can help me.

Here is my code:

```
  <p:contextMenu id="schadenTableContextMenu" for="todoSchadenTable"
     style="width: 200px; ">

     <p:submenu id="schadenTableSetAsReadSBM" label="Markieren als"
        styleClass="my-menu">
        <p:menuitem id="schadenTableSetAsReadSBMMI1" value="Gelesen"
           style="width: 167px;" icon="ui-icon-mail-open" ajax="true"
           partialSubmit="true" process="@this"
           action="#{todoLeseHistController.setAlsGelesen()}" update=":mainForm" />

        <p:menuitem id="schadenTableSetAsReadSBMMI2" value="Ungelesen"
           style="width: 167px;" icon="ui-icon-mail-closed" ajax="true"
           partialSubmit="true" process="@this"
           action="#{todoLeseHistController.setAlsUngelesen()}"
           update=":mainForm" />
     </p:submenu>

     <p:menuitem id="schadenTableContextMenuMI3"
        style="width:190px !important; font-size:12px !important;"
        value="In der Applikation öffnen" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
        title="Öffnet den ToDo in der entsprechenden Applikation." ajax="true"
        partialSubmit="true" process="@this"
        action="#{openExternalLinkController.openTodoInExtUrl()}"
        oncomplete="openExternal(xhr, status, args)" update=":msgGrowl" />

  </p:contextMenu>

 -------------------dataTable-----------------
<p:dataTable id="todoSchadenTable" widgetVar="todoSchadenTableW"
     emptyMessage="Keine Schadenmeldungen gefunden." var="currentTableItem"
     value="#{schadenTableController.dataModel}" paginator="true" rows="15"
     filteredValue="#{schadenTableController.filteredTodos}"
     filterEvent="keyup" filterDelay="500"
     sortBy="#{currentTableItem.angelegtAm}" sortOrder="descending"
     editable="true"
     rendered="#{(loginBean.loggedIn and !mitViewController.leiterViewActiv and mitViewController.schadenTabActive) or (loginBean.loggedIn and leiterTreeController.todoSchadenTableAktiv)}"
     selection="#{schadenTableController.selectedSchadenmeldungen}"
     rowKey="#{currentTableItem.meldungId}"
     style="min-width:1700px !important;">

     <p:ajax event="rowEdit" global="false" partialSubmit="true"
        listener="#{schadenTableController.saveErlVorgelBis(currentTableItem)}" />

     <!-- <p:ajax event="rowSelect" global="false" listener="#{todoLeseHistController.aktuelleSchadenMeldung(currentTableItem)}" /> -->

     <p:ajax event="contextMenu" global="false" partialSubmit="true"
        listener="#{todoLeseHistController.testeMich()}" />

     <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="zuordnenZuButton"
        partialSubmit="true" process="@this" global="false" />
     <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update="@this" partialSubmit="true"
        process="@this" global="false"  listener="#{todoLeseHistController.testeMich()}"/>
     <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update="@this" partialSubmit="true"
        process="@this" global="false" />


     <f:facet name="header">
        <p:commandButton value="Zuordnen" id="zuordnenZuButton" ajax="true"
           partialSubmit="true" process="@this"
           label="Schandemeldung einem Mitarbeiter zuordnen"
           oncomplete="zuordnenDialogW.show();"
           disabled="#{not schadenTableController.hasSelectedSchadenmeldungen}"
           action="#{zuordnenDialogController.prepareDataForTable()}"
           style="float: left;" />
        <pe:tooltip for="zuordnenZuButton"
           value="Ausgwählte Schadenmeldungen einem Benutzer zuordnen"
           myPosition="left center" atPosition="right center" showEffect="fadeIn"
           hideEffect="fadeOut" showDelay="700" />
        <h:outputText
           value="#{schadenTableController.tableHeaderName} - #{leiterTreeController.getDataTableHeaderZusatz()}"
           style="color:#cf0008; font-size: 22px;  padding-top: 7px; " />
     </f:facet>


                   ...
```

Comment: Have you checked the PF showcase? Their example of DataTable with ContextMenu seems to cover your question and it works even without the need to select the row before right-clicking: http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/contextMenu.xhtml

Comment: @Sva.Mu Yes, i checked the PF-showcase. But that is another example, it's only single selection.
However, it may be that they fixed this since this question is quite old.

Comment: Check out if this fixes your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506098/implementing-a-dynamic-contextmenu-for-a-primefaces-multi-select-datatable/32865746#32865746

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the selected row to a variable in the backing bean when you call the listener for contextMenu event?

It should look something like this:

```
        <p:ajax event="contextMenu"  listener="#{backingBean.contextMenuSelect}" />
```

and this in the backing bean:

```
        public void contextMenuSelect(SelectEvent event) {
             selectedRow = (EntityClassName) event.getObject();
        }
```