# p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener and context menu issues

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

**p:contextMenu**

```
<p:contextMenu for="dt" id="_context_menu">
  <p:menuitem value="View Distribution" update="act_dist_dt" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{bankTransactionInqMB.viewDisctributionAcct}" onsuccess="act_dist.show()" />
  <p:menuitem value="Issued" update="dt" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{bankTransactionInqMB.issuedOrUpdate}" rendered="#{bankTransactionInqMB.issueOrUpdate == true}" />
  <p:menuitem value="Cleared" update="dt" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{bankTransactionInqMB.postBankTransaction}" rendered="#{bankTransactionInqMB.cleared == true}" />
  <p:menuitem value="Posted" update="dt" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{bankTransactionInqMB.clearBankTransaction}" rendered="#{bankTransactionInqMB.posted == true}" />
</p:contextMenu>
```

**p:dataTable**

```
<p:dataTable var="item" id="dt" style="width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;" value="#{bankTransactionInqMB.bankTransactions}" rows="15" paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink} " rowKey="#{item.id}" selectionMode="single" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                selection="#{bankTransactionInqMB.bankTransaction}">


  ....

  <p:ajax event="contextMenu"  listener="#{bankTransactionInqMB.contextMenuListener}" update=":main:_context_menu" oncomplete="_context_menu.show()" />
            </p:dataTable>
```

When I right click on datatable it show context menu and then instantly disappear and on every next right click context menu appears but listener="#{bankTransactionInqMB.contextMenuListener}" not called.It is only called on first time right click.

**I have 2 issues:**

1. listener call only first time right click and subsequent right click
   not call the listener
2. context menu appear and instantly disappears on first time right
   click

I basically want to implement dynamic context menu for each row. when user right click , listener will decide which menu should be visible or not for specific row .

any update ?

Comment: hi. I've also thought of doing something like this but it seems that the <p:ajax event="contextMenu" update=":main:_context_menu" /> is the one making the contextmenu disappear.

Comment: @Fritz what u have adopted alternative solution ?

Comment: well i avoided having to make a dynamic contextMenu altogether. (note: i even tried using the contextMenu model but still it wouldn't work) i just made an error message if the menuitem selected is not fit for the selection.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32865746/6065134)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the show is called on the context menu before the update, and then the update hides the menu.

I've found a solution, by replacing the JS of primefaces.

**p:contextMenu**

```
<p:contextMenu for="dt" id="_context_menu" widgetVar="_context_menu">
  ....
</p:contextMenu>
```

**p:dataTable**

```
<p:dataTable id="dt" .... >        
    ....

    <p:ajax event="contextMenu"  update=":main:_context_menu" oncomplete="PF('_context_menu').show(currentEvent);" listener="#{bankTransactionInqMB.contextMenuListener}" />

    ....                
</p:dataTable>
```

*Add the following JavaScript :* **contextMenu.js**

```
var currentEvent;

   $(document).ready(function() {
      PrimeFaces.widget.ContextMenu.prototype.show = function(e) {
         //hide other contextmenus if any
         $(document.body).children('.ui-contextmenu:visible').hide();

         if(e) {
            currentEvent = e;
         }

         var win = $(window),
         left = e.pageX,
         top = e.pageY,
         width = this.jq.outerWidth(),
         height = this.jq.outerHeight();

         //collision detection for window boundaries
         if((left + width) > (win.width())+ win.scrollLeft()) {
            left = left - width;
         }
         if((top + height ) > (win.height() + win.scrollTop())) {
            top = top - height;
         }

         if(this.cfg.beforeShow) {
            this.cfg.beforeShow.call(this);
         }

         this.jq.css({
            'left': left,
            'top': top,
            'z-index': ++PrimeFaces.zindex
         }).show();

         e.preventDefault();
      };
   });
```

And it works.
Source : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=26813#p93374

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I found it can be done easier:

`<p:contextMenu id="ctx_menu_dt_dilutions" 
     beforeShow="window.currentContextMenuEvent=arguments[0]">...`

and

`<p:dataTable id="dt" .... >        
    ....

    <p:ajax event="contextMenu"  update=":main:_context_menu" oncomplete="PF('_context_menu').show(window.currentContextMenuEvent);"  />`

Comment: Wow @flack is that i was looking for! I needed update contextmenu (menuitems) before show, but everytime i put update on <p:ajax contextmenu hides.
Thanks for your trick